# Understanding Quaternion

Tags: quaternions

Can anyone please help me understand how to form orientation quaternion from raw accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer data? Also, like Euler angles, does the order of rotation have an effect on the orientation quaternion since it has an angle component to it?

Comment: Tried MathOverflow ??

Comment: If you use angles you must be aware of the [gimbal lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno),  so the point of quaternions is to escape gimbal lock. Blender uses quaternion so have a peek there I guess if you want to know more.

Comment: The most standard way in the industry is https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7fa5/eebe34cd2efc0b48eb60fb62fbd0bb5f33ba.pdf